# Using multiple array-contains in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the following code, I want to use multiple array-contains queries, which is inappropriate according to firebase limitations.

```
await firestore
      .collection("collection")
      .where("field1", "array-contains", value1)
      .where("field2", "array-contains", value2)
      .where("field3", "array-contains", value3)
      .get();
```

Tried to find a workaround solution by adding all values to one array and query on that array but it seems firebase does not support array-contains-all query.

Any suggestion how can I reframe my query?

Comment: are you trying to use "field1" equals to value1 OR "field2" equals to value2  etc. or  "field1" equals to value1 AND "field2" equals to value2? because OR option is not possible in firebase as far as I know

Comment: To understand better, you have three arrays in each document, and you want to filter the document that exists in `collection`, by different values that exist in each array. Is that correct? Can you please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.